# How to keep the ToggleButton status after re-enable

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I want to keep the ToggleButton status after re-enable the ToggleButton.But It keep turning off.

Here is my ToggleButton when the Ellipse is actived:

[image]

When the ToggleLock is turned on:

[image]

After unlocking:

[image]

It's wrong color.It have to turn to green color.

**My code and Style:**

```
<!--EllipseToggleButton Style-->
<Style TargetType="ToggleButton"
  x:Key="EllipseToggleButton"> 
  <Setter Property="Margin"
  Value="20 10 0 10" />
  <Setter Property="Height"
  Value="30" />
  <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
  Value="Top" />
  <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
  Value="False" />
  <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
  Value="{x:Null}" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
   <Grid Name="contain">
   <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
   <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
   <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
   <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
   <Storyboard>
   <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="icon"
   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(Color)"
   To="#3D727272"
   Duration="0" />
   </Storyboard>
   </VisualState>
   </VisualStateGroup>
   <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckedStates">
   <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
   <Storyboard>
   <ColorAnimation x:Name="IconCheckedColorAni"
   Storyboard.TargetName="icon" Duration="0"
   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
   To="#FF68E80F" />
   </Storyboard>
   </VisualState>
   <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
   </VisualStateGroup>
   </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
   <Ellipse Name="icon"
   Height="24"
   Width="24"
   Stretch="Uniform"
   VerticalAlignment="Center"
   Cursor="Hand"
   Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
   </Grid>
  </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

**MainWindow:**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleLock"
  Content="Lock"
  Width="100"
  Margin="20 10 0 10"
  VerticalAlignment="Top"
  Height="30" />
  <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource EllipseToggleButton}"
  IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ToggleLock, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource InBConv}}"
  Background="Red" />
</StackPanel>
```

**Converter:**

```
class InvertBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    if (value != null && value is bool)
    {
      return !(bool)value;
    }
    return false;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ToggleButton` does retain its `IsChecked` value while it is disabled. When it is re-enabled, however, the visuals don't match: When you un-toggle the lock, you activate the `CommonStates.Normal` visual state group, which, near as I can tell, resets the default value on the `Ellipse` named `icon` :

```
Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
```

...making it red. You'll find you need to click the ellipsis twice in order to make it green again.

Since the ellipsis toggle button doesn't change its `IsChecked` value, the `CheckedStates` visual state storyboards aren't invoked.

I haven't found any way to fix this in XAML (tried reordering triggers, writing out all states explicitly and so on), but you can work around it by forcing an `IsChecked` state change from code-behind:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleLock"
        Content="Lock"
        Width="100"
        Margin="20 10 0 10"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Height="30"
        Checked="OnChecked"
        Unchecked="OnChecked" />
    <ToggleButton
        x:Name="toggleButton"
        Style="{StaticResource EllipseToggleButton}"
        IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ToggleLock, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource InBConv}}"
        Background="Red" />
</StackPanel>
```

...with the following event handler:

```
private void OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool? isChecked = this.toggleButton.IsChecked;
    toggleButton.IsChecked = null;
    toggleButton.IsChecked = isChecked;
}
```

I don't know that this is the best possible solution, but it does work, and may serve as a starting point for further investigation.

Comment: thanks for the help!.Yes,It's hard to find a way to fix.In your solution I still can un-toggle/toggle the ellipse.@Petter Hesselberg.

Answer (score 1):

I think the source of your problem is using the same element for 2 different VisualStateGroup. As you can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc296245(v=vs.95).aspx) there is an element named "DisabledVisualElement" to handle "Disabled" VisualState that is separate from the element that handles "CheckStates" VisualStateGroup.

Following that, I added another ellipse named "iconDisabled" to the template that has **Opacity="0"** and its value changes to **"1"** in "Disabled" VisualState. Also, I added **Opacity="1"** to your "icon" and it will change to **"0"** in "Disabled" VisualState.

Here is your modified **style code**:

```
    <Style TargetType="ToggleButton"
           x:Key="EllipseToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="Margin"
                Value="20 10 0 10" />
        <Setter Property="Height"
                Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
                Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
                Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Grid Name="contain">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="iconDisable"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="icon"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckedStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation x:Name="IconCheckedColorAni"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="icon" Duration="0"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                        To="#FF68E80F" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation x:Name="IconUncheckedColorAni"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="icon" Duration="0"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                        To="Red" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Ellipse Name="icon"
                                 Height="24"
                                 Width="24"
                                 Opacity="1"
                                 Stretch="Uniform"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 Cursor="Hand"
                                 Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                        <Ellipse Name="iconDisable"
                                 Height="24"
                                 Width="24"
                                 Opacity="0"
                                 Stretch="Uniform"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 Cursor="Hand"
                                 Fill="#3D727272" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Other parts of the code are the same as **you wrote in question post**.

Comment: thank for your solution! using 2 shapes. I didn't think of it.will check it when I get home.@TheSETJ

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **IsHitTestVisible** instead of **IsEnabled**.
Here is the way I fixed my issue:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleLock"
        IsChecked="{Binding OptionLocked}"
        Content="Lock"
        Width="100"
        Margin="20 10 0 10"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Height="30" />
<ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton"
        IsChecked="{Binding EllipseChecked}"
        Style="{StaticResource EllipseToggleButton}"
        IsHitTestVisible ="{Binding OptionLocked, Converter={StaticResource InvertBoolConv}}"/>
```

I having another issue.I can't set background color to Gray when the ToggleLock is turning on.At least it's working.I will accept it if no more answer come in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

I want to say thank Petter Hesselberg and TheSETJ.

Finally I have fixed it.Here is a new ControlTemplate:

```
<ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
        </VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckedStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
        <Storyboard>
        <ColorAnimation x:Name="IconCheckedColorAni"
            Storyboard.TargetName="icon"
            Duration="0"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" />
        </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
        </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Ellipse Name="icon"
            Height="24"
            Width="24"
            Stretch="Uniform"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Cursor="Hand"
            Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            Visibility="Visible" />
            <Ellipse Name="iconDisable"
            Height="24"
            Width="24"
            Stretch="Uniform"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Cursor="Hand"
            IsHitTestVisible="{TemplateBinding IsHitTestVisible}"
            Fill="3D727272"
            Visibility="Collapsed" />
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsHitTestVisible">
        <Trigger.Value>
            <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
        </Trigger.Value>
        <Setter TargetName="iconDisable"
            Property="Visibility"
            Value="Visible" />
            <Setter TargetName="icon"
            Property="Visibility"
            Value="Collapsed" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHitTestVisible">
            <Trigger.Value>
                <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
            </Trigger.Value>
             <Setter TargetName="iconDisable"
                Property="Visibility"
                Value="Collapsed" />
                <Setter TargetName="icon"
                Property="Visibility"
                Value="Visible" />
        </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And **MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleLock"
        IsChecked="{Binding OptionLocked}"
        Content="Lock"
        Width="100"
        Margin="20 10 0 10"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Height="30" />
<ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton"
        IsChecked="{Binding EllipseChecked}"
        Style="{StaticResource EllipseToggleButton}"
        IsHitTestVisible ="{Binding OptionLocked, Converter={StaticResource InvertBoolConv}}"/>
```